# How to create custom ConfigVersion.cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am creating a c++ header only library and using CMake as my build system. I am pretty new with CMake, but after I read some blog posts, documentation and looked at other projects I managed to write working `CMakeLists.txt`.

I have a problem with expressing compatibility of different versions of my project. I am currently using in `write_basic_package_version_file`, `COMPATIBILITY SameMinorVersion`. But it doesn't work for me. As I just started writing my library I expect there to be a lot of API breaking changes before reaching version `1.0`. So I want my project to have following rules:

1. When major version is 0 then minor versions are incompatible with each other
2. When major version is 1 or greater minor versions are compatible with each oher

I want a mix of `SameMajorVersion` and `SameMinorVersion` depending on current major version. CMake however doesn't give me this option. It's official [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#command:write_basic_package_version_file) says:

> If your project has more elaborated version matching rules, you will need to write your own custom ConfigVersion.cmake file instead of using this macro.

I have searched in many places, but I can't find anywhere information about how to create this custom file. I looked into one that CMake generated (by calling `write_basic_package_version_file` macro), but it looks really intimidating and I don't understand it really well.

**So my request is**: Could someone show me how to write `ConfigVersion.cmake` file so that it follows rules I specified above? Or point me to documentation that describes this or even link me to some project that already does this?

I include for reference part of my `CMakeLists.txt` that describes how to export and install my project:

```cmake
include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY SameMinorVersion
)

configure_package_config_file(
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION
  ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
  NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
)

install(FILES
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake)

install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/chimp DESTINATION include)
```

Comment: Take the auto-generated one and modify it to whatever you need. It is just a file with a bunch of checks. Note, however, that your library should not have some exotic version comparison lest the users would struggle with it.

Comment: @ixSci Thank you. I am afraid that it is all I have left and I will have to read it line by line and try to understand what to change, and and what not. But I don't think my versioning is exotic. It is quite understandable and used for example in Rust's world in crates.io repository.